# kotlin android proguard error

Tags: android, proguard, kotlin

I'm trying to build an apk and proguard it but it fails with messages like:

```
Error:ProGuard: [radis] Warning: kotlin.dom.EventListenerHandler: can't find superclass or interface org.w3c.dom.events.EventListener
Error:ProGuard: [radis] Warning: kotlin.dom.CloseableEventListener: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.events.EventTarget
Error:ProGuard: [radis] Warning: kotlin.dom.CloseableEventListener: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.events.EventListener
Error:ProGuard: [radis] Warning: kotlin.dom.DomPackage: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.events.MouseEvent
Error:ProGuard: [radis] Warning: kotlin.dom.DomPackage: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.events.Event
```

I added in my proguard.cfg, -dontwarn on kotlin.dom.** but it does not help.

Answer (score 6):

I was not using standard proguard-android-optimized so I edited my config to match as much as possible (I have ACRA config as well) and add -dontwarn kotlin.** and -dontwarn org.w3c.dom.events.* and it's proguarding now.

Another problem pops up with Dexing I'm still investigating

Comment: My dexing problem disappeared after a migration to Crashlytics and Gradle

Comment: Darn, I was hoping it might have been related to the issue I was having. Proguard seems to struggle with anonymous inner classes that extend from abstract ones